# Dynamo DB - Table Design for Lists

Tags: list, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Dynamo DB.

I have a table User to store user info and user's music playlist.
Music playlist contains a number of mp3 urls.
How do I store it in Dynamo DB for efficiency.

My User JSON Design: 
Key is userid

```
{
 "userid":"",
 "shuffle":"",
 "folderid":"",
 "lastsong:"",
 "playlist": [ { "url1", "url2","url3"......100s of urls }]
}
```

Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, I would divide the playlist table into a separate table. In this type of database it is better to have more information than to penalize the speed of reading when making a query or a scan.
If your playlist info is only made of Urls maybe in this way it would be fine, as you have shown it, beause you can treat it as a List in any programming lenguage, but if in a future you have to include more info... it will be more complex

The hash key of the playlist table ,if you need in a future to add more info, should be the userid.